# How Javascript => operator works?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how this => works. I googled "javascript =>" but found no good answer.

var isTriangle = (a,b,c) => Math.max(a,b,c)<(a+b+c)/2

Comment: Also, read [the operator reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

This is the new ECMAScript 6 fat arrow syntax for defining functions. Your example:

```
(a,b,c) => Math.max(a,b,c)<(a+b+c)/2
```

is approximately equal to:

```
function(a, b, c) { return Math.max(a,b,c)<(a+b+c)/2; }
```

...but a lot shorter.

[This site has more examples.](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/arrows-es6/)

Comment: I got it. Thank you.